# HttpsURLConnection seems to misdirect openConnection() when URL contains special characters

Tags: java, url, character, httpsurlconnection

I'm am trying to replace a working SSLSocket based implementation with one based on HttpsURLConnection instead. When I use a valid URL that contains special characters, every HTTPS request I have tried returns status 403 with my HttpsURLConnection implementation. Meanwhile, the same URLs return status 200 with my SSLSocket implementation.

Can anyone see any reason that a HTTPS request would return 200 with SSLSocket, but return 403 with HttpsURLConnection?

Here is the **SSLSocket** implementation:

```
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class UseSslSocket
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException
    {
        String host = "www.google.com";
        String resource = "/search?q=weather";

        TrustManager[] trustAllCert = new TrustManager[]
                {
                        new X509TrustManager()
                        {
                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                            {
                                return null;
                            }
                            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
                            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
                        }
                };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCert, new SecureRandom());
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());
        SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslFactory.createSocket(host, 443);

        Writer streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
        String rn = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        streamWriter.write("GET "+ resource +" HTTP/1.1"+ rn +"Connection:close"+ rn +"Host:"+ host + rn + rn);
        streamWriter.flush();

        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sslSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        String response = new String();
        for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; response += line + rn);

        streamWriter.close();
        bufferedReader.close();
        sslSocket.close();

        System.out.println("https://"+ host + resource +" >> "+ response.substring(0, response.indexOf(rn)));
//        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Here is the **HttpsURLConnection** implementation:

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class UseUrlConnect
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, URISyntaxException, IOException
    {
        String host = "www.google.com";
        String resource = "/search?q=weather";

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                {
                        new X509TrustManager()
                        {
                            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                            {
                                return null;
                            }
                            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
                            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType){}
                        }
                };
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier()
        {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
        URL url = new URI("https://"+ host + resource).toURL();
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        String response = new String();
        for (String line; (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null; response += line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        bufferedReader.close();

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

PS: The **trustAllCert** stuff is present so that self-signed certificates can be accepted.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=weather
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
 at UseUrlConnect.main(UseUrlConnect.java:45)`

Comment: Judging only from your title, I might guess that you are not encoding your URLs properly.  Is there any chance that the URL causing the error has some unencoded characters in it?

Comment: `URL url = new URI("https://www.google.com/search?q=weather").toURL();` is an example that returns 200 in SSLSocket, but 403 in HttpsURLConnection. Does HttpsURLConnection require some other method of encoding?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that URL, and `HttpsURLConnection` in Android should certainly trust Google.  I'm not sure I know why this isn't working.